# Swift 3 App has black frame on Ipad 3

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I recently started learning to code with Swift on Xcode and I made a simple app that works fine but the sizing is a tad strange on the only physical device I have to test it on, my Ipad 3. The app's main frame is smaller than the Ipad's width and height?

I have automatic sizing (Constraints) set up and I'm positive I've done it right.

Using Swift 3

I notice while the iPad 3 supports iOS 9 it isn't on the "simulator list" and thought that it's not fully supported or something? can someone confirm or provide a fix?

- My app supports iOS 8+
- And is using Constraints

[image]

Comment: Notice the "1x" in the corner? Your app is an iPhone-only app. It's not an iPad app or a Universal (supports both) app.

Comment: @rmaddy that simple? can that be changed after creation or does it has to be set at the start? Thanks for you quick answer! I was a bit confused if it's only an iPhone app, that it still lets me test it on iPad etc..

Comment: All iPhone-only apps can be run on an iPad. They run in a simulated iPhone 3.5" mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help and linking to other question! I look but couldn't find anything helpful! cheers